# submitting PHP - HTML DATE to MySQL DATE

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

i would like to help with my code how to edit HTML input date into MySQL TIMESTEMP format cause my SQL code is invalid and data are not added to my database, Thanks for help

also i asking to check this code on bottom cause 2nd SQL deppends on 1st SQL, thanks

```
if (isset($_POST['pridaj_anime_submit'])) {
   $sql_vloz_anime = "INSERT INTO anime (a_name, a_year, a_translated_min, a_translated_max, a_rate_min, a_rate_max, a_edit, a_condition)
                              VALUES ('$_POST[nazov]', '$_POST[rok]', '0', '$_POST[pocet]', '8', '10', '$_POST[preklad]', '$_POST[stav]')";
   mysqli_query($connect_to_db , $sql_vloz_anime);
   $sql_ziskaj_a_id_pridaneho_anime = "SELECT * FROM anime WHERE a_name = '$_POST[nazov]'";
   $run_sql_ziskaj_a_id_pridaneho_anime = mysqli_query($sql_ziskaj_a_id_pridaneho_anime);
   $a_id_ziskane = "";
while ($db_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql_ziskaj_a_id_pridaneho_anime)) {
    $a_id_ziskane = $db_data['a_id'];
}

   $sql_vloz_anime_info = "INSERT INTO anime_info (a_id, a_img, a_start, a_stop, a_time_ep, a_akihabara)
                                        VALUES ('$a_id_ziskane' , '$_POST[obrazok]', '$_POST[zaciatok]', '$_POST[koniec]', '$_POST[cas]', '$_POST[akihabara]')";
   mysqli_query($connect_to_db , $sql_vloz_anime_info);
}
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Save yourself syntax problems and protect your code from SQL injection.

Comment: Please take a look at http://bobby-tables.com - Your code runs at a really high risk of SQL injection. NEVER put user-inputs directly in querys, use prepared statements instead. For more information see the posted link.

Comment: @Twinfriends checked it :) thx gonna go fix whole project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$input_date=$_POST['date'];
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($input_date));
```

This will convert input date into MySQL Timestamp compliant format.
Please DO NOT put POST values directly in your queries. Your website or web application will be hacked in no time through SQL Injections.

Answer (score 1):

MySql datetime considered `yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s` format.

Your input date is like `dd-mm-yyyy h:i:s` and so on.

Then use convert date to `yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s`. Read [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) manual.

For e.g.

```
$inputDate = '06-06-2017 05:21:34';
$mysqlDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($inputDate));

// MySql Query.
INSERT INTO table_name SET `your_field`='$mysqlDate'
```